# How to differentiate my views in DRF swagger (yasg)?

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I have an api made with djangorestframework and I want to add a swagger. It works well. In my api I have some views that require authentication with Basic or JWT so I set this up in my settings. The problem is that in my swagger gui I do not manage to tell which view is not requiring authentication. Do you know how to do that.

```
#api/urls.py
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Snippets API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Test description",
      terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
      contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
      license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny],
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('mesures/', views.get_all),
    path('mesure-add/', views.add_mesure),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='obtain_tokens'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='refresh_token'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('register/', views.register_user),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]
```

In my settings.py

```
# in my settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=int(os.getenv("TOKEN_DAYS_LIFE"))), 
}

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
      'Basic': {
            'type': 'basic'
      },
      'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
      }
   }
}
```

In my views.py

```
#views.py
@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['post'], request_body=MesureSerializer)
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_mesure(request):
    serializer = MesureSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
    # this is to provide the user automatically from token auth
    # no need to provide it from the post request
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer._errors)

@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['post'], request_body=UserSerializer)
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

as you can see my view register_user should not show a authentication in my swagger but this is not the case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok, I just needed to use the `security=[]` in `@swagger_auto_schema` for the specific view I want to tell there is no authentication required.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['post'], request_body=UserSerializer, security=[])
```